# PDFBox set field value doesn't work

Tags: pdfbox, pdf-form

I'm trying to set values in a pdf form that has enabled input fields but  nothing appears.
In my pdf there is a check box that enables the input field, so first I check it then I set the value in the field which has been enabled, but when I save my pdf my value doesn't appear.
This is my code:

```
PDTextField pdfField = (PDTextField) acroForm.getField("info_15a");
pdfField.setValue("xxxxxx");
```

no errors, no exception.
So, what can I do?
Thanks,
Barbara

Comment: Please share the PDF in question.

Comment: Please tell what version you are using

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I'm using PDFBox 2.0.8

Comment: @mkl this is the pdf https://www.inps.it/Nuovoportaleinps/image.aspx?iIDModulo=7712&tipomodulo=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field "info_15a" in your document has the annotation flag **Hidden** set. So even though PDFBox properly fills in that form field, you don't see anything.

To make the form fill-in visible, you also have to un-hide the form field widget, e.g. like this:

```
PDTextField pdfField = (PDTextField) acroForm.getField("info_15a");
pdfField.getWidgets().get(0).setHidden(false);
pdfField.setValue("xxxxxx");
```

*([FillInForm](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/form/FillInForm.java#L129) test `testFillLikeBarbara`)*

<sub>As you say you can save the PDF, I assume you have no problems with the facts that the original PDF is encrypted and that is has a usage rights signature.</sub>